# ODP .NET AQ Getting Exception Messages Queue

Tags: database, oracle, message-queue, odp.net

How can I dequeue Exception Messages from a Oracle Message Queue using ODP?
I'm using the default queue for exceptions.

Thanks!!

Comment: Solved!
dbms_aqadm.start_queue (queue_name => 'YOURQUEUENAME', enqueue => FALSE, dequeue => TRUE);